# Why does DirectoryEntry("WinNT://") not show group everyone?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, permissions, directoryservices

The below function (is supposed to) lists all groups on the local machine.
Now the question: Why does the "everyone" group not show up ?
If I change directory permissions as user, I see the "everyone" group, so it must be there, somewhere.

```
    Public Shared Function GetAllGroups() As DataTable
        Return GetAllGroups(System.Environment.MachineName)
    End Function


    ' Tools.Permissions.Local.GetAllGroups() '
    Public Shared Function GetAllGroups(ByVal strDomain As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow = Nothing

        Try
            Dim bException As Boolean = False
            Dim deLocalMachine As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + strDomain)
            'Dim deRootObject As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry(strPath, strUserName, strPassword, bException) '
            If bException Then
                Return Nothing
            End If


            For Each child As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry In deLocalMachine.Children
                Try

                    If StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(child.SchemaClassName, "group") Then

                        If Not dt.Columns.Contains("Members") Then
                            dt.Columns.Add("Members", GetType(System.String))
                        End If

                        For Each strPropertyName As String In child.Properties.PropertyNames
                            If Not dt.Columns.Contains(strPropertyName) Then
                                dt.Columns.Add(strPropertyName, GetType(System.String))
                            End If
                        Next strPropertyName

                        dr = dt.NewRow

                        Dim strMembers As String = ""
                        For Each member As Object In DirectCast(child.Invoke("Members"), IEnumerable)
                            Using memberEntry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(member)

                                Try
                                    strMembers += memberEntry.Properties("Name").Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine
                                    Console.WriteLine(memberEntry.Path)
                                Catch exFixMeIsNotNullNotWorking As Exception

                                End Try

                            End Using
                        Next

                        dr("Members") = strMembers

                        For Each strPropertyName As String In child.Properties.PropertyNames

                            If StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(strPropertyName, "objectSid") Then
                                Dim strSID As String = ""
                                Try
                                    Dim sidThisSid As New System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(child.Properties(strPropertyName).Value, 0)
                                    strSID = sidThisSid.ToString()
                                    ' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040623/convert-a-username-to-a-sid-string-in-c-net '
                                    '  NTAccount ntAccount = (NTAccount)sid.Translate( typeof( NTAccount ) ); '
                                    ' Dim ntAccount As Security.Principal.NTAccount = CType(sidThisSid.Translate(GetType(Security.Principal.NTAccount)), Security.Principal.NTAccount) '
                                Catch ex As Exception

                                End Try

                                dr(strPropertyName) = strSID
                            Else
                                dr(strPropertyName) = child.Properties(strPropertyName).Value.ToString()
                            End If



                        Next strPropertyName
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception ' Don't finish just because one fails
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString & vbLf & vbLf & ex.StackTrace.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "FEHLER ...")
                End Try
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString & vbLf & vbLf & ex.StackTrace.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "FEHLER ...")
        End Try

        Return dt
    End Function ' ListEverything
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your current solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Everyone` group isn't a standard group but rather an implicit group or built-in principal. If you open your local "Users and Groups" you won't see it listed there either. The same is true of other "groups" such as `Authenticated Users`. If you want to access these you need to use the [`System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype.aspx) enumeration. This [Windows 2008 article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd637754.aspx) is really relevant for older versions of Windows, too.

Comment: @Quandary, the `Administrators` groups is actually a regular group like you would create such as `Marketing`. But since it is required it still shows up in the `WellKnownSidType` which can be confusing. I usually think of the implicit groups as more groups that are dependent upon a situation. For instance, my account isn't a member of `Terminal Server User` until I login remotely.