# C# - How do I get the "Everybody" user?

Tags: c#, acl

I already wrote a code which can create a share and change permissions for the current user. The goal was to always allow all for everybody on share level and deny rights on ntfs acl level.

I use a german windows and I noticed that I only can access the everybody user by using "jeder". In english it would be the user "everybody" or "all" I think?! Anyway I'm searching for a way to get the name of the everybody user language independent.

Hope this is possible.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The name that the English version of Windows uses is "**Everyone**".

You can get the user regardless of language by using the *[WellKnownSidType.WorldSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype.aspx)* value:

```
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
var account = (NTAccount) sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the way to do it has been answered here: [How can I get the local group name for guests/administrators ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212862/how-can-i-get-the-local-group-name-for-guests-administrators)

This "everyone" SID is a well known SID "S-1-1-0" (the list is availalble here: [Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330/en-us)).