# .Net CryptographicException "Object already exists" on Azure

Tags: .net, azure, cryptography, azure-web-app-service, cryptographicexception

We have a website deployed on two web apps on Azure : a production and a pre-production version.

The website at certain time creates a container to host RSA keys, using the below code :

```
// -----------------------------
// Part 1 : Initialize csp params
// -----------------------------
const int PROVIDER_RSA_FULL = 1;
const string CONTAINER_NAME = "OurKeyContainer";
CspParameters cspParams;
cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL);
cspParams.KeyContainerName = CONTAINER_NAME;
cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
cspParams.ProviderName = "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider";

// --------------------------------------------------
// Part 2 : A try to set folder access rights to "everyone"
// --------------------------------------------------
// http://whowish-programming.blogspot.fr/2010/10/systemsecuritycryptographycryptographic.html
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013881/c-sharp-how-do-i-get-the-everybody-user
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
var rule = new CryptoKeyAccessRule(sid, CryptoKeyRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
cspParams.CryptoKeySecurity = new CryptoKeySecurity();
cspParams.CryptoKeySecurity.SetAccessRule(rule);

return new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
```

The issue is that this code works only for one of the website, the one that was first launched actually. The second one threw a CryptographicException "Object already exists".

After googling , the issue seems to be caused by users executing the website  that do not have right to access the key container, but unfortunately the recommended fix (implemented in Part 2 on our code above) does not work ..

Any idea or advice ?

Thanks

Riana

Comment: Have you tried to [Granting Read Access to an RSA Encryption Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede.aspx#Y898) for the identity of your failed web app via KUDU? You could find location of Aspnet_regiis.exe file [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx).

Comment: Hi Bruce and thanks for your response. I read the url you sent but the aspnet_regiis command is not recognized by Azure console nor Kudu .. Any advices ?

Comment: For .NET Framework version 4 (32-bit systems), you could change your dir to `D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`, and for .NET Framework version 4 (64-bit systems), you could change your dir to `D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` via KUDU.

Comment: I managed to run [the recommended command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Y898)¶and it told me it has suceeded ,then I restarted my websites .. but unfortunately, I still have the same exception .. :-( .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are basically trying to create a Machine wide container with the same name two times. I am assuming that the `pre-prod` and `prod` environments are on the same machine, perhaps as deployment slots in your App Service? I could replicate your problem with this setup at least. There are some other setups that could produce the same situation I guess, but this is the most likely.

There are three things you can change in this setup that will produce different results:

- Identity to grant access
- Container store
- Container name

For identity we can use either `Everyone` (as you have tried) or `Current` which we can get from WindowsIdentity

```cs
    private IdentityReference GetWindowsIdentity()
    {
        return System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
    }

    private IdentityReference GetEveryoneIdentity()
    {
        return new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
    }
```

The container store can be either `machine wide` or just for the current user

```cs
// machine wide store
var cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL)
{
    ...
    Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
    ...
};

// default store
var cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL)
{
    ...
    Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;
    ...
};
```

And for the store name we can choose something, in your case you choose the same but we can set something that is unique for the identity as well

```cs
    KeyContainerName = "OurKeyContainer",

    KeyContainerName = $"OurKeyContainer-{identity}",
```

The different combinations will produce different results:

**Everyone identity, machine wide store, same container name** Fails on one of the slots with `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Object already exists.`

**Everyone identity, machine wide store, container per identity** OK

**Everyone identity, user store, same container name** Fails on both of the slots with `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.`

**Everyone identity, user store, container per identity** OK

**Current identity, machine wide store, same container name** Fails on one of the slots with `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Object already exists.`

**Current identity, machine wide store, container per identity** OK

**Current identity, user store, same container name** Fails on both of the slots with `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.`

**Current identity, user store, container per identity** Fails on both of the slots with `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.`

So, to summarize, **changing the name of the container** to include something that is unique for the environment will fix the problem. It doesn't have to be the identity (but you will get one identity per App Service you are running on a machine so it is fairly safe), it could be the name of the environment if you set it as an `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE` in your App Service and make sure it is set to `pre-prod` and `prod` respectively.

[Here is the playaround code to test it](https://gist.github.com/FredrikGoransson/2dc613052fe31222453c7ce5a3f2a5d7)

Comment: Hi, and thank you very much for taking time to make all those tests ! I'm just wondering what is the possible disadvanges of using many different key container to host the same key ?

Comment: It depends on if you want to/need to use them from other sources? I think a good separator could be per environment. Not sure what dissadvantages there might be, I think it depends a lot on how you are using the container and what you store in it. But I cant (at the moment) see any real disadvantages to having one container per environment/machine key at least.