# Convert SID's to usernames/groups?

Tags: c#, usergroups, sid

I'm looping through a network directory and trying to output the user/group names (permissions) associated with each file/folder. I'm getting the SID's back but I want the names like "group_test" and not "S-1-5-32-544". Here's my code -

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

                foreach (var f in files2)
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(f);
                    var fs = fileInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);

                    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in fs.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
                    {
                        var value = rule.IdentityReference.Value;
                        Response.Write(string.Format("File: {0} \t Usergroup: {1} <br/>", fileInfo.Name, value));
                    }  }
```

I get SID's from the above code but in the foreach loop, if I use this instead -

```
(NTAccount)((SecurityIdentifier)rule.IdentityReference).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value
```

I get this exception -
`Some or all identity references could not be translated.`

It appears that the Translate method does not work on remote shares. How do I retrieve the real names of the SID's? The remote server does not have LDAP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to resolve a SID that is *local* to a remote machine.  As the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499053/how-can-i-convert-from-a-sid-to-an-account-name-in-c) states:

> The SecurityReference object's Translate method does work on non-local SIDs but only for domain accounts...

This [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/dc973f8c-4fd9-41f3-82a9-3646721e9dbd/) provides an example for remotely resolving a SID using WMI which is probably the best method for accomplishing your task.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use WMI you should be able to do it via the [Win32_UserAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class I think. It has a `Name` property and a `SID` property.

Or the [Win32_Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class for the groups.

Here's an article for connecting to a remote pc using WMI that has C# code: [How To: Connect to a Remote Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)