# How to determine if a string is a User SID?

Tags: c#, windows

In Windows Operating System, user SIDs are represented with a string such as :

> S-5-1-76-1812374880-3438888550-261701130-6117

Is there any way that I can identify that such a string is a valid User SID?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for validation or verification? For verification simply try to get an account from the SID. ([How can I convert from a SID to an account name in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/499053/1386111))

Comment: No, I'm looking for verification. Thanks

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata He suggested a solution for verification - `For verification simply try to get an account from the SID.`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to [Security Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246018.aspx) description, SID has following form (it has one to fourteen subauthority values):

```
S-1-<identifier authority>-<sub1>-<sub2>-…-<subn>-<rid>
```

You can use regular expression to check if string matches this pattern:

```
string input = "S-5-1-76-1812374880-3438888550-261701130-6117";
string sidPattern = @"^S-\d-\d+-(\d+-){1,14}\d+$";
bool isValidFormat = Regex.IsMatch(input, sidPattern);
```

That will ensure that **input string has valid format**, but that will not prove that SID is valid. As suggested in comments, you should try get account if you need to check if you have valid SID.

Comment: A little bit wrong: `World SID` (aka `Everyone`) with value `S-1-1-0` does not pass your pattern.

Answer (score 11):

I found this slight variation helpful which allows for some well known security identifiers. For example, the well known sid Everyone S-1-1-0

```
^S-\d-(\d+-){1,14}\d+$
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good idea to rely on a regex to check if a SID is valid. For one, the only valid SID version is 1 so this regex will think
`S-9-(\d+-){1,14}\d+`
is valid when 9 is not a valid version. However fixing the regex to only allow version 1 would fail should there ever by a new SID version or even a completely new SID format. The better way to do this is let the system decide if the SID is valid. Just do this:

```
string notSureIfSID = "S-9-5-76-1812374880-3438888550-261701130-6117";
bool sidIsValid = false;
bool sidIsAccount = false;
try {
    SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(notSureIfSID);
    sidIsValid = true;
    sidIsAccount = sid.IsAccountSid();
}
catch (ArgumentException) {
    // Handle invalid SID
}
```

If the SID format is invalid (if, for instance the version is not 1 or the number of sub-authorities is over 15 or less than 1) the constructor will throw an ArgumentException. If you want to check if the SID is an actual existing account, just call `IsAccountSid` on the `SecurityIdentifier`.

Comment: `IsAccountSid()` just checks if sid matches `S-1-5-21-D-D-D-X` wheres `S-1-5-21` is default for all windows computers (domain or not), `D` is `Domain SID` and it is always same for all domain SIDsm and X is `RID` which increments almost for each new object in domain.  This means that AD Group, Local account and Computer account will pass `IsAccountSID` as True.

And you can loose functionality by ignoring Non-Account SIDs like `S-1-1-0 Everyone`

Answer (score 1):

The regex shoud be "S-\d-\d-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+-\w+"

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check SID is SID, use [SecurityIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier) constructor inside `try\catch`.

This will **not** validate that this sid belongs to anyone\anything in the whole world.

---

SIDs are

- Always start with `S`
- For current, always continue with `-1-` *(this is SID version, and there is only one)*
- Continues with single [SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid_identifier_authority) which is not more than 6 bytes, means this value is not more than `281474976710656` (15 characters)
- Continues with [1..14] `-` separated [SID_IDENTIFIER_SUBAUTHORITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-getsidsubauthority) which are not more than 4 bytes wide (10 characters max)
- Optionally ends with RID `-` separated which is not more than 4 bytes wide (10 characters max)

More detailed refer to [MS-AZOD, chapter 1.1.1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-azod/)