# How can I convert a SID to an account name in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, security, powershell

This question is inspired by [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499053/how-can-i-convert-from-a-sid-to-an-account-name-in-c-sharp) using the C# tag. If I have a Windows SID, and would like to convert it to a readable account name, how can I achieve this using PowerShell instead of C#?

Right now, I have the following code, which retrieves the group memberships for the currently logged on user account:

```
$Identity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
$Identity.Groups;
```

The results of the `Groups` property does not give me any account names, only SIDs. If I pipe the output from the `Groups` property into PowerShell's `Get-Member` cmdlet, I can see that the resulting objects are `System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier` objects. However, looking at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and Intellisense) for the `Groups` property shows that it is returning an `IdentityReferenceCollection` object.

How do I convert these `SecurityIdentifier` objects into proper names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use the [`Translate()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.translate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the [`SecurityIdentifier` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The single parameter for this method is a reference to the .NET type that you would like to convert the `SecurityIdentifier` to. If you examine [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/636786/189198) to the similar C# question, you will see that you can simply pass in a reference to the [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.ntaccount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The resulting code would look something like this:

```
$Identity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
foreach ($Group in $Identity.Groups) {
    $Group.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

One way of resolving SIDs to account names is using the [`Win32_SID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class:

```
PS C:\> $sid = 'S-1-5-18'
PS C:\> [wmi]"Win32_SID.SID='$sid'"


__GENUS              : 2
__CLASS              : Win32_SID
__SUPERCLASS         :
__DYNASTY            : Win32_SID
__RELPATH            : Win32_SID.SID="S-1-5-18"
__PROPERTY_COUNT     : 5
__DERIVATION         : {}
__SERVER             : CARBON
__NAMESPACE          : root\cimv2
__PATH               : \\CARBON\root\cimv2:Win32_SID.SID="S-1-5-18"
AccountName          : SYSTEM
BinaryRepresentation : {1, 1, 0, 0...}
ReferencedDomainName : NT-AUTHORITY
SID                  : S-1-5-18
SidLength            : 12
PSComputerName       : CARBON
```

Comment: Good alternative. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have the answer already - I wrote a wrapper a short while back that also searches a list of [well known SIDs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330), if it helps.  [ConvertFrom-SID](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ConvertFrom-SID-Map-SID-to-dcb354d9)

A generic way you could pull this out would be as follows, where $sid holds a SID string:

```
$sid = '<SIDGoesHere>';
$objSID = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier -ArgumentList $sid;
$name = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value;
```

Cheers!

Comment: Just documenting on SO :)

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but link-only answers are strongly discouraged [for these reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/228805). You should include the code in your answer (adding the link is okay), otherwise this is really more of a comment than an answer. In its current form  your post stands a good chance of being automatically flagged for the Low Quality Posts review queue and deleted.

Comment: @CookieMonster: Just wanted to give you a heads up that even though your `New-Object` syntax will technically work, it's deceiving because it looks like C# code, which PowerShell is definitely not. I made an edit to spell things out more clearly in PowerShell syntax.