# Use WMI to convert a remote SID to username

Tags: powershell, wmi, remote-access, wmic, sid

I am using `Invoke-WMIMethod` to identify all SIDS beginning with `S-1-5-21`, like so (thanks to [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)):

```
$Keys = Invoke-WmiMethod -Path $ClassPath -Name EnumKey -ArgumentList 2147483651,'' 
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty sNames | Where-Object {$_ -match 'S-1-5-21-[\d\-]+$'}
```

I want to convert these SIDs from the remote system to usernames on the remote system using WMI. Is this possible through WMI or `Invoke-WmiMethod`?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than grabbing from the registry you could get the same information from the `Win32_UserProfile` provider. Then if folder name is good enough, consider something like this:

```
$Computer = "ExampleComputer"
Get-WMIObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter "SID like 'S-1-5-21-*'"  -ComputerName $Computer |
    select SID,@{name=LocalPath;Expression={Split-Path -leaf $_.LocalPath}}
```

Otherwise `Win32_UserAccount` exists but can be really slow with a large domain.

```
$Computer = "ExampleComputer"
$SIDs = Get-WMIObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter "SID like 'S-1-5-21-*'"  -ComputerName $Computer | select -ExpandProperty SID
$UserAccounts = Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -ComputerName $Computer
foreach ($SID in $SIDs) {
    foreach ($Account in $UserAccounts) {
        If ($SID -eq $Account.SID) {
            $Account
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [use the `Win32_SID` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22332325/712649) to obtain the account name:

```
foreach($Key in $Keys)
{
    $SID = [wmi]"\\$RemoteComputer\root\cimv2:Win32_SID.SID=$Key"
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        SID = $Key
        Username = $SID.ReferencedDomainName,$SID.AccountName -join '\'
    }
}
```

Comment: I get `Cannot convert value "\\<remotecomputer>\root\cimv2:Win32_SID.SID=S-1-5-21-3201..." to type "System.Management.ManagementObject".
 Error: "Invalid parameter "`

Comment: Looks like you need to have quote marks around the Key part. So the command should read : 
$SID = [wmi]"\\$RemoteComputer\root\cimv2:Win32_SID.SID='$Key'"