# NTFS permissions show name but script shows SID

Tags: powershell, permissions

I run a script to get permissions to a file share.

Recently i've had to add permissions from users in a separate domain.

Now when i run the script, the script returns the SID of the users, rather than their names. However if i go into the NTFS properties, the UI shows the names.

I assume since it takes awhile for NTFS to actually reference the SID to the name before it shows the name (as initially it too only shows SID) - that the script is just running and pulling the data without waiting for reference... but i don't see a 'busy' member for the get-item cmdlet...

And unfortunately since i don't have access to the other domain, i wouldn't be able to run another command to get the user names from the SID.

If push comes to shove i'll either have to get access to that domain, or run the script under an account that does - but i was just wondering if there was something i could do in my current position.

Any ideas?

```
((((Get-Item "D:\shares\sharelocation").GetAccessControl('access')).Access).identityreference).value
```

Comment: It most certainly isn't a timing problem. Do you see SIDs for all accounts or just for those from foreign domains? Can you manually translate the SIDs ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22331668/1630171))?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers it's only showing SID's from that 1 foreign domain that i don't have access to.

Comment: Can you manually translate the SIDs?